# How do I tab the next column instead of next row?

Tags: c#, tabindex

So here's my array of groupbox columns with textboxes inside.

[image: Table]

What I want to do is make it so that the when the user tabs it will go to the next column and remain the same row.

Ex: If the user is in the 2nd column, 1st row, it should go to the 3rd column 1st row. However, what's happening based on my code is that it is going down then when it reaches to the bottom, it will go to the next row and go up from there.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[,] statsBonus = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox[6, 3]; // x, y
private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox[] statsCol = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox[6];

    for (int j = 0; j < statsCol.Length; j++)
    {
        statsCol[j] = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.statsCol[j].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.statsCol[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(190 + j * 80, 20);
        this.statsCol[j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 100);
        this.statsCol[j].TabIndex = j + 1;
        this.statsCol[j].TabStop = false;
        this.statsCol[j].Text = statsLabel[j];
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(statsCol[j]);

        for (int i = 0; i < statsBonus.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            statsBonus[j, i] = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.statsBonus[j, i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 20);
            this.statsBonus[j, i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.statsBonus[j, i].TabIndex = i + 1;

            this.statsBonus[j, i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            this.statsBonus[j, i].Dock = DockStyle.None;
            Point pt = this.statsCol[j].DisplayRectangle.Location;
            pt.X += (this.statsCol[j].DisplayRectangle.Width - this.statsBonus[j, i].Width) / 2;

            pt.Y = 20 + i * 25;

            this.statsBonus[j, i].Location = pt;
            this.statsBonus[j, i].Text = "0";

            statsBonus[j, i].Parent = this;
            this.statsCol[j].Controls.Add(statsBonus[j, i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

comment or remove below line

```
//this.statsCol[j].TabIndex = j + 1;
```

and chenge below line

```
this.statsBonus[j, i].TabIndex = i + 1;
```

as

```
 this.statsBonus[j, i].TabIndex = statsBonus.GetLength(1)*j + i+ 1;
```

Comment: I removed `this.statsCol[j].TabIndex = j + 1; line` and `this.statsBonus[j, i].TabIndex = i + 1;` Then I added `this.statsBonus[j, i].TabIndex = statsBonus.GetLength(1)*j + 1;` in the inner loop but it's still giving me the same result

Comment: @RafaelF. I did exactly what he said and tried what you did but I'm still getting the same thing :(

Comment: @RafaelF. It isn't working either. Did you test it maybe on a clean project?